# Using while Loop in perl

Tags: perl, selenium

I am very new to perl.
I am developing one script in perl using selenium. I have one .pl file in which I have one button`(Test and Save)`. My logic is I want to click on that button again and again until its exist. I have used following command.

```
while ($sel->is_element_present ("//Button[text()='Test and Save']"))
{$sel->clickAndWait("//Button[text()='Test and Save']");}
```

But the problem is its not coming out the loop even the Button got disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element may be present on the page but not visible.  Try `is_visible()` instead.

(Also, try viewing the source of the page to confirm whether the element is still present but not visible.)

Comment: Thanks . is_visible() is giving me the desired result.